TypeScript invariance and structural type checking on nested generics strange behavior
I've encountered strange behavior when using complex nested generics.
Here is the distilled version of my real-life problem:
type Variable = 'A' | 'B';

type Option<T extends Variable> = T extends any ? { value: T } : never;

type OptionAny = Option<Variable>;

type Generic<T extends Variable> = Extract<OptionAny, { value: T }>;

// ==============================================================================
// JUST IN CASE, IF YOU'RE CURIOUS, THIS IS FINE:
type GenericHandler<T extends Generic<Variable>> = { handle(input: T): void };
// no error
type GenericHandlerA = GenericHandler<Generic<'A'>>;
// ==============================================================================

type NestedGeneric<T extends Variable> = { generic: Generic<T> };

type NestedGenericHandler<T extends NestedGeneric<Variable>> = {
  handle(input: T): void;
};

// error
//  TS2344: Type NestedGeneric<'A'> does not satisfy the constraint NestedGeneric<Variable>
//    Type Variable is not assignable to type 'A'
//      Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'A'
type NestedGenericHandlerA = NestedGenericHandler<NestedGeneric<'A'>>;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// the expected solution (to my understanding of TS):
// use distributive conditional type on type, that is nesting another generic
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// distribute over possibly union T
type NestedGenericDistributive<T extends Variable> = T extends any
  ? { generic: Generic<T> }
  : null;

type NestedGenericDistributiveHandler<
  T extends NestedGenericDistributive<Variable>
> = {
  handle(input: T): void;
};

// ok
type NestedGenericDistributiveHandlerA = NestedGenericDistributiveHandler<
  NestedGenericDistributive<'A'>
>;

// ok, too
type NestedGenericDistributiveHandlerA2 = NestedGenericDistributiveHandler<
  NestedGeneric<'A'>
>;

// because:
type TestDistributive = NestedGenericDistributive<Variable>;
//   ^? {generic: Generic<"A">} | {generic: Generic<"B">}

type TestNonDistributive = NestedGeneric<Variable>;
//   ^? {generic: Generic<"A" | "B">}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Now, the bloody black magic:
// Use type aliases for either the constraint or concrete NestedGeneric type
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

type NestedGenericAliasAny = NestedGeneric<Variable>;
type NestedGenericAliasHandler<T extends NestedGenericAliasAny> = {
  handle(input: T): void;
};
// no error
type NestedGenericAliasHandlerA = NestedGenericAliasHandler<NestedGeneric<'A'>>;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

type NestedGenericAAlias = NestedGeneric<'A'>;
// no error
type NestedGenericHandlerAAlias = NestedGenericHandler<NestedGenericAAlias>;

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// More bloody magic...
// Replacing `Generic` with:
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// doesn't help
type GenericDistributiveBad<T extends Variable> = T extends any
  ? Extract<OptionAny, { value: T }>
  : null;

// even though
type TestBad = GenericDistributiveBad<Variable>;
//   ^? | Extract<{value: "A"} | {value: "B"}, {value: "A"}>
//      | Extract<{value: "A"} | {value: "B"}, {value: "B"}>

// But this does help
type GenericDistributiveGood<T extends Variable> =
  | (T extends 'A' ? { value: T } : never)
  | (T extends 'B' ? { value: T } : never);

// Is this different to `TestBad`?
type TestGood = GenericDistributiveGood<Variable>;
//   ^? {value: "A"} | {value: "B"}

// afterall, `Extract` is
//    `type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never;`
// which means that each type in the TestBad union must go through the following:
//  Extract<{value: "A"} | {value: "B"}, {value: "A"}>
//    is equal to
//      | ({value: "A"} extends {value: "A"} ? {value: "A"} : never)
//      | ({value: "B"} extends {value: "A"} ? {value: "B"} : never)
// same for Extract<{value: "A"} | {value: "B"}, {value: "B"}>
//  ...
// Result is: {value: "A"} | {value: "B"}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Oh, and BTW
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

type TestGeneric = Generic<'A' | 'B'>;
//   ^? {value: "A"} | {value: "B"}

// :)


Can anybody explain strictly how it works and why?
(Goodluck answering this with ChatGPT)

To my understanding typescript should just try to check if NestedGeneric<'A'> is assignable to constraint NestedGeneric<Variable>
While doing it, it should check if type parameter T in NestedType is invariant or covariant (correct me if I am messing up the terminology). If the NestedType is a distributive conditional type over T, the T is covariant, otherwise, by default, it is invariant. If it is invariant, and the given type (of T) is not exactly the same as the constraint, ts throws an error.
Otherwise, it goes deeper.
Therefore
type NestedGenericHandlerA = NestedGenericHandler<NestedGeneric<'A'>>;

raises TS error, and the "expected solution" works
type NestedGenericDistributive<T extends Variable> = T extends any
  ? { generic: Generic<T> }
  : null;

this is covariant case and everything is ok.
So, the first question is - is the above explanation correct?

Now, if it is correct, then what is going on in the code that goes below the "expected solution"?

usually distribution helps to solve a problem when instead of Generic<A|B> you need Generic<A> | Generic <B>

@AlexanderNenashev
I know. And this is reflected in an "expected solution" part.
The question about the weird parts below it.

Please [edit] to make sure you're asking one very specific question and only one question. Otherwise this risks being closed as needing focus. If your question is "is the above explanation correct" then that's fine. If it's "what's going on in the code" that's too broad, you should ask a specific and more precise question.
